# Can thermal paste damage CPU and video card some time after applying?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, thermal-paste

Three weeks ago, I disassembled my notebook to clean its heat sink.  I re-applied thermal paste and re-assembled it.  It worked well, until about three weeks when it hard shut down while I was working with it.  When I tried to turn it on again, it only got as far as the desktop before shutting off.  After a day, the power button did nothing at all.

Service said that there was a problem with the video card being unsoldered and soldered a new one in, but it has stopped booting again.  Now I think that I may have applied applied more thermal compound than usual and that it somehow damaged my CPU or video card.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't believe much "service" says...

Comment: I had no alternative, as I'm not good at these things unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Is it silver-based thermal paste? If so, its not particularly conductive to electricity, but it does have some capacitance. If it is in contact with any of the connections on the CPU, motherboard, RAM, or video card, it could potentially cause the problems you are encountering. It can essentially slow down data flow, which can generate errors causing the system to shut down, particularly if it gets on the RAM.

If there is any extra anywhere in your system, it would be a good idea to try to remove it carefully.

Comment: no its white-based paste. No it RAM is in background of motherboard. I will disassemble it and clean anyway. But main question for me is, why it worked 3 weeks, then stopped? then problem is other thing?

Comment: And if now, laptop doesn't boot up, it means that motherboard is damaged?

Comment: We're talking about the element silver, not the color.  I don't know what "white-based" paste is.

Comment: @Javidan It's not the colour that's relevant; its the content. If the paste is white, it is less likely to contain silver, but it is still possible. It's difficult to say exactly whether any components are damaged just from this. The only way to tell is for you to clean any contaminated components and see whether it boots up. It is possible for thermal paste to cause intermittent problems, like the ones you have experienced.

Comment: Ah sorry about "white-based". I will try.

Comment: @Wolves - Are you suggesting he shouldn't use Silver based thermal paste?  Because some of the best thermal paste on the market is made from it.

Comment: @Ramhound No. I'm suggesting he should not use it in excess. A tiny amount of thermal paste is all that is necessary.

Comment: @Wolves - I would agree.  I was just making sure.  You mention the possible conductive properties of the paste so it sounded like you were warning against silver based thermal paste.

Comment: @Ramhound Yep :) I use silver thermal paste. But spreading it all over the electronics would be very bad. I've used a small tube on 4 CPUs, still have about half left :)

Comment: White thermal post is often titanium oxide based. Regardless of what the thermal compound is made of, you only need to use a tiny amount. It is not supposed to conduct the heat. It is supposed to fill the holes between the CPU and the heatsink. And those holes are in polished metal.